# How can I add a new tab to the product description page in Drupal 8?

Tags: menu, tabs, navigation, product, drupal-8

How can I add a new tab to the product description page in Drupal 8?

---

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to make a [local task](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks)